# Create checkbox list from related divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create number of checkbox based on the number of array values returned from jQuery. Here is my code:

```
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="dog"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="cat"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
```

Ineed to display the result value in HTML like this:

```
<label>
    <input class="fish" type="checkbox" />
    fish 
</label>
<label>
    <input class="cat" type="checkbox" />
    cat 
</label>
<label>
    <input class="dog" type="checkbox" />
    dog 
</label>
```

This is what I tried:

```
var items = {};
$('div.bob').each(function() {
    items[$(this).attr('data-xyz')] = true; 
});

var result = new Array();
for(var i in items) {
    result.push(i);
}
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in two loops, one to create the array of items to create checkboxes for and other to create the checkboxes themselves:

```
var items = $.unique($('.bob').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('xyz');
}).get());

var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    html += '<label><input  class="' + items[i] + '" type="checkbox" />' + items[i] + '</label>'
}
$('.checkboxes').append(html);
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jx99s1vf/)

Or you could do this in a single loop, creating the checkboxes as you go:

```
var html = '';
$('.bob').each(function() { 
    var item = $(this).data('xyz');
    if (!$('input.' + item).length)
        $('.checkboxes').append('<label><input class="' + item + '" type="checkbox" />' + item + '</label>');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wj8awhLo/)

The former has the pro of making less calls to the DOM, but has to make two loops through the data.

Comment: is it possible with same class name?? like class="abc" data-abc=""' + item + '""

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('div.bob').each(function() {
    items.push($(this).attr('data-xyz'));
});

//assuming containerid is the div where u want to append checkboxes
for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
    $('#containerId').append('<input type="checkbox" name="'+ items[i]+'" />')
}
```